# What am I doing wrong in this QBO v3 API Attachments upload filemaker pro 19 request

Tags: file-upload, quickbooks, filemaker

I am trying to upload attachment to an invoice to QBO through Filemaker Pro 19.

When I run the following code it shows the following error.

Error: "System Failure Error: Could find no Content-Disposition header within part"

[image]

Comment: Where is the file saved?
To upload, it should be saved in a variable and add it to the data part with @ notation @$file.

Refer the last answer in this thread,
https://community.claris.com/en/s/question/0D50H0000829gW7SAI/curl-file-upload-via-form

Answer (score 0):

you will need to reference the file from a container field. Check the -F curl option in the filemaker help to see the syntax for referencing a container field.